# Distortion when using displacement modifier

Tags: uv, displacement

So I'm modeling a ring for myself, and I'm using a moon surface texture as a displacement map using a UV unwrap of just the outside of the mesh.
But the displacement modifier seems to be afftecting parts of the mesh I don't want. You can see below that the internal diameter increases.

[image]

And I don't want this as obviously it will chance the ring size and it won't fit.
Also I'm wanting the displacement to only affext the surface and for it to stay flush with the top of the ring but it has these sides that I want to get rid of.

[image]

Any help or tips will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Displacement modifier has a 'vertex group' option which allows to displace only the vertices affected to this group.

Comment: Thanks for that Lemon!
I'm trying to get rid of the raised edge circled below. I tried editing the actual texture, put a black faded edge, but for some reason I still get the raised section. Maybe sculpting is the easiest way?


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dCAN2.jpg

Comment: If I understand you well... simply remove the sides from the vertex group... or I don't get the point?

Comment: I haven't got the sides in the group, when I apply the displacement modifier, on the edge of the vertex group/UV map I get this big dip at the sides:
 [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/y9sVE.png

I've tried editing the UV map with a black edge in varying shades, but I still get that dip on the edge of the displacement where I want it to smoothly join.
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/g8Hdh.png
The only way I can think is to apply the modifier, select all the edges in the bottom of the dip and scale, but that would be a very tedious task.

Comment: Vertex groups is a way to assign a value to the vertices of the group. This per vertex value can be between 0 and 1. About that and concerning the displacement modifier, the displacement will be max when the value is 1, intermediate when the value is 0.5 and there will be no displacement when 0. So simply use the vertex paint to lower the displacement on the border (you can make it smooth to 0 to the borders)

Comment: Sorry: in the last comment I said "vertex paint", but I wanted to say "vertex **weight** paint"

Comment: Thanks for the continued support!
Is it the midl value you're talking about? Because when I set that value to 0, I get a large offset from the original surface
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Unu4i.png
Then at 1, I get a large offset in the opposite direction.
 [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EFdUm.png
And at 0.1, I'm still getting the dip at the edge of the displacement border.
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7knGP.png

Comment: ok, as I am not sure of what we are talking about finally, is that what you want to obtain? https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Yq2o.jpg. If yes, I'll write an answer about it.

Comment: My explanation hasn't been great so I've broken it down.
1: I'm getting a big dip all the way round the ring at both ends of the displacement And the only way around I can think is to actually apply the modifier, and then select all the edges in the 'dip' and scale up.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/1dH9t.jpg

Comment: Problem 2: Once I solve problem 1, rather than going straight into the displacement and having a big edge, I want a smooth transition. I tried to achieve this by adding a fade to the edges of my texture, but it doesn't seem to work, is this where vertex weight painting comes into play?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jp8pS.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way to obtain a smooth transition from a displaced surface to the non displaced parts is to use a vertex group and to assign the good value for the vertex weights:

[image]

Here is a view of the weights (blue = the smallest value = 0, red = the highest value = 1):

[image]

This is done with the following steps (some of them will depend on your actual mesh and the way the ring is modeled):

- Create a vertex group: in the property panel, use the "plus" button as below

[image]

- In the displacement modifier, assign the group:

[image]

- Now we have to assign vertices to the group and fix their weights

This part depend on how the model is done. 
Here I used a parallelepiped base, set an array on it, then subsurface and a curve:

[image]

To assign the wanted vertices:

- Select them
- Tune the value of the weight
- And assign

[image]

So going progressively to the border, while decreasing the weight value to 0, you obtain a smooth edge.

The values are visible vertex per vertex on the right side panel:

[image]

[The blend file](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/2908/)

Comment: Apologies for my late response, just back from holiday. Your response was perfect and helped me so much. Thank you very much